# Pandas pivot_table ordering / axis string formatting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have time series data. I want to preserve the order of this time series data for analysis and plotting purposes. I want to view this data in a pivotted format also.

In the code below, I get some daily time series data and pivot this. I want to be able to plot it so it shows the graph with the lines on top of each other (i.e. year on year). To do this I need to remove the year from the index (and pivot on this).

If I want to preserve the order of this so it remains correct for analysis and plotting, how can I? At the moment I have a 'work around' which is formatting by month *then* day - that way the order is preserved.

But, if I wanted to change the order to day *then* month, then the order is incorrect. Or if I just want to display the month (e.g. Jan, Feb...) on the x-axis of the chart, then how can I do this?

I am wondering how it is best to pivot this data? Is it best to use month-day like I have done, then format the axis afterward? If so, how? Or is there a better way to pivot this data so that I don't have to worry about this and can use some sort of date formatter on the x-axis?

The overall result I am looking for is kind of like if I used `index=df.index.dayofyear` in the pivot_table, but I want to be able to change the format to days, months, maybe both etc, so I would like to not result to using day of year, but something equivalent.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fake time series dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2017', end='31-12-2020', freq='D')
data = np.random.randn(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['Data'])

# pivot to get by month in rows, then year in columns
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                          index=df.index.strftime('%m-%d'), 
                          columns=df.index.year, 
                          values='Data')

# plot
ax = df_pivot.plot(title='Data by Year', figsize=(6,4))
ax.get_lines()[-1].set_linewidth(3)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

ax.figure.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try Matplotlib's [date module](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/dates_api.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean? To rename the axis? Or to manipulate the pivot table?